# IE 11 angular scope return function instead of object

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

```
$scope.updateCart = function() {

    item = $scope.productData;
```

This code snippet returns a function in IE 11 instead of object like it does on chrome

which cause the following $http request to send garbled data.

using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js

**Previous title: IE 11 jquery 'Argument not optional' error**

The following code:

```
    dt = $.param({
            shopid: shop_id,
            mtd: method,
            item: item
        });
```

throw the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument not optional
   at add (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:7340:4)
   at buildParams (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:7392:3)
   at jQuery.param (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:7360:4)
   at $scope.updateBACart (http://127.0.0.1:6636/js/baCartNg.js?v=1478430971:104:3)
   at fn (Function code:2:216)
   at expensiveCheckFn (http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js:15485:11)
   at callback (http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js:25018:17)
   at Scope.prototype.$eval (http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js:17229:9)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js:17329:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js:25023:17)
```

The error is thrown in IE 11 but not in chrome

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

I change the code:

```
    dt = $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
            shopid: shop_id,
            mtd: method,
            item: item
        });
```

now the code doesn't throw error, but the request is

```
   item: %0Afunction+item()+%7B%0A++++%5Bnative+code%5D%0A%7D%0A
   mtd: add
   shopid: 1
```

instead of the item data.

Comment: From the output of that last snippet, it looks like your `item` variable is actually holding a *function*. Perhaps you simply forgot to call the function, e.g. something like `var item = elements.item` where it should be `var item = elements.item(0)`? Try adding a `console.log(item)` before that line and see what gets logged in the browser's console.

Comment: I notice that, this is the value I get from the NG scope - which is wrong in IE 11 (vs chrome)

Comment: Weird that it would be different between IE and Chrome. I think you'll need to show us some more code, so others can have a better understanding of what's going on with your variables.

Comment: My guess is that this is actually not about differences between IE and Chrome *per se*, but more like a race condition where the `item` is something else (a Promise, maybe) when the execution speed varies. Seeing more code would definately help to identify the exact problem.

Comment: Always provide a [mcve]. The snippets shown only leave people guessing and the first one is very incomplete

Comment: charlietfl - this is a minimal, complete example -  did you test it?

Comment: Please don't vote down something if you can't unswer it -I put a lot of effort into this.

Comment: You would have gotten better answers much more quickly if you had posted some more relevant code in your question. Your original code did not show *how* you assigned the `item` variable - which is absolutely **key** into understanding what is going on with the rest of your code. Instead, you ended up with a solution yourself, which is actually just a workaround that even *you* don't understand. It also doesn't show why `item1` works but `item` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can name your variable `item1` instead of `item` and that will work for now... but that doesn't tell you anything about what's **wrong** with your original code.

The **real** problem is that you are assigning to a global variable instead of to a local variable. When you use:

```
function () {
    item = (2 + 2); // or some other value
}
```

without using `var item` before it, you are actually assigning to a *global* variable `item`. In the browser context, the global scope is the `window` object, so the above is equivalent to:

```
function () {
    window.item = (2 + 2);
}
```

In Chrome, there's no problem: initially there was no `window.item`, so this assignment creates it. In IE11 however, `window` already has an `item` property, and it is **read only**! That means that all assignments to the global `item` variable are silently ignored, so `window.item` always has its original function value.

Your "solution" works around this by using a different variable name. A better, more robust and more efficient solution would be to use *locally scoped* variables instead:

```
function () {
    var item = (2 + 2); // does NOT create a global item variable
}
```

As a good practice, make sure that you *always* use `var` when declaring a new variable, to avoid accidentally creating global variables. Even better, add a `"use strict"` directive to your function(s) so that these kinds of assignments throw errors rather than silently ignoring errors.

If you really need to create a global variable, explicitly assign to a property on the `window` object itself:

```
function () {
    window.globalItem = (2 + 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `item1 = $scope.productData;` instead of `item = $scope.productData;`

For some reason IE11 set `item` to `function item() { [native code] }`

Comment: I see what's going on. Since you use `item = ...` rather than `var item = ...`, your code is trying to assign a **global** variable `item`. On Chrome, this is not problem as there is no `window.item`. IE however seems to have a `window.item` function, and it's **read only**. That means that your assignment with `item = ...` actually *fails*, and reading `item` later still gives you the original `window.item`. In short, the **real** problem is that your variables are leaking to the global scope - use `var`!